# Check Firestore Database boolean return value

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working for a task related to react native app based user management. After they successful sign up themselves as a user, I include a data which is store Boolean value and I have named it as emailVerifiedAccount (this is the stored data if they registered themselves successful and indicate if they are a verified user if they click on email verification link send to them). In login screen I would like to check the Boolean value that I get from firestore in onAuthStateChanged and only direct them to index screen when the emailVerifiedAccount that I get is return true. Code below is authstatechanged for login screen .

```js
    const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
        if (user) {
            checkEmailVerifiedAccount=firestoreService.isEmailVerifiedAccount(user);
            try {
                if(checkEmailVerifiedAccount===true){
                    navigation.navigate('Index');
                }else{
                    Alert.alert(
                        "Verify as a Playbookx user",
                        "Please click on email verification link send to your email. If you do not receive any email ,please contact user support",
                        "You may come back to login again after you verified your email",
                        [
                          { text: "OK"}
                        ]
                      )
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    };
```

and in firestore.js is where all the code and function that is related with Firestore database. isEmailVerifiedAccount is one of the class object which checking verified user using email.

```
isEmailVerifiedAccount = async (user) => {

return await firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists){
            const user=snapshot.data();
            const emailVerifiedAccount={
                emailVerifiedAccount:user.emailVerifiedAccount
            };
            return emailVerifiedAccount
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And the problem that I facing right now is that, it lead me to index screen when the emailVerifiedAccount in Firestore is false. Picture below is the structure for Firestore.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `isEmailVerifiedAccount` function is asynchronous, so when calling it you have to `await` the result:

```
checkEmailVerifiedAccount = await firestoreService.isEmailVerifiedAccount(user);
```

Comment: Hi Frank, but if i writing await in onAuthStateChanged it gave me an syntax error saying that "Unexpected reserved work 'await' ". Sorry kinda new to react native and firebase.

Comment: You'll need to mark this method as `async`: `const onAuthStateChanged = async (user) => {`. I highly recommend reading about what [`async` and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) do, and why they always go together.

Answer (score 0):

```
const checkEmailVerifiedAccount = firestoreService.isEmailVerifiedAccount(user);
```

`checkEmailVerifiedAcccount` seems to be an object but you are checking if it's equal to `true`. Either return `user.emailVerifiedAccount` directly from `isEmailVerifiedAccount` function or read that property like this:

```js
const checkEmailVerifiedAccount = firestoreService.isEmailVerifiedAccount(user);

if(checkEmailVerifiedAccount.emailVerifiedAccount) {
  navigation.navigate('Index');
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, the code that u given me seem to go to index screen even through the emailVerifiedAccount in firestore is false.